# I get rapid eye movement as soon as meditation starts

Tags: meditation, beginner

I saw a question about rapid eye movement when meditating, which from what I know is similar to REM sleep and the experience I had is a little bit different. As the title says I get the eye movement with in a few seconds and the only difference is the top of both my eyes hurt a little and can be distracting sometimes. Is it good that I can get this so fast?  Does it mean some kind of raise in consciousness or even more concentration may come soon?

I have only recently noticed this this week and I meditate about 20 minutes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eye movement during meditation](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/8522/eye-movement-during-meditation)

Answer (score 1):

In short this can be due to:

- past fabrications surfacing rapidly and creating uncommon experiences
- perhaps less likely but a possibility is [Piti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%ABti) which sometimes create vibrating and / or pulsating experiences

Also see: [eye movement during meditation](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/8693/295)

These experiences are neither good nor bad. Also do not get attached or averse to them. In additions concentrate on the task at hand than giving importance and distracting your self when there experiences do arise in your meditation session.

Comment: I guess I will just have to experience it for my self and find out that way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it good that I can get this so fast?

Why do you assume getting REM during meditation is a good thing?

Buddhist meditation is about stilling/calming the mind and body, about contemplating the truths to break free from the ten fetters. Getting REM and the eyes hurting is more distraction and suffering.

When humans get REM in sleep, they are unaware of such REMs. Instead they usually are external signs that the person asleep is dreaming. For a person to be consciously be aware of his/her REMs during Buddhist meditation session is not a desired goal or experience. Therefore I would have to say no, its not a good thing.

> Does it mean some kind of raise in consciousness or even more concentration may come soon?

No in my experience.

Strongly suggest that you speak with a respected and experienced meditation instructor.

What happens when you just close your eyes? Do you get REM then? If so, I would also recommend seeing a GP.

May you be happy.

Comment: I asking "is it good" as in is it good or bad. I have martial arts instructors who have plenty of experience. And no the REM only happens during meditation

Comment: @Morihei1883:I've added to my answer above. You say that you get REM within seconds of starting meditation. Usually, the physiology of the 1st few seconds of most meditators, is no different from a person simply closing one's eyes & taking a few breaths. The main difference is intention. So if you just close your eyes & take a few breaths without the intention to meditate and do NOT get REM, but if you do the same with the intention of meditating for long and do get REM, then that's something you will have to discuss with an experienced meditation instructor. I do not think its a good thing.

Comment: I forgot to add my breathing is always deep even out of my meditation. My intention is rarely negative. I will be careful from now on but from what I know REM sleep is where you dream, so could it be a vision is emerging. I have had some struggles with abusing marijuana not so long ago, and I've heard drugs cloud the mind's eye. Still this makes me too worried to meditate now. Should I stop? thank you for the feedback

Comment: @Morihei1883: Yes, REM is an outward sign that someone asleep is dreaming. However, the person asleep is not aware of the REM. What sort of meditation do you practice? Do you have a guide/teacher? I cannot comment further, but it seems that you may have some very strong expectations of your meditation practice. In Buddhism meditation is used for letting go and letting the mind calm. Do not stop, keep searching. I wish you well.