# Shaking REM and movement

Tags: reference-request

i Wanted to know what kind of experience i had today while i meditated.

I meditated after a long time and it lasted 1,5 hours. I started shaking after a while, then twitching my eyes, REM and after some time i started moving.. It was n a rythm. sometimes sideways, sometimes down towards the floor and so on. And when i wanted to stop my meditation i came back to my first position, then shaking, eyemovement, twitching and back to normal. Did something like this happen to anyone? Is it a good or a bad sign?
Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I get rapid eye movement as soon as meditation starts](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/14642/i-get-rapid-eye-movement-as-soon-as-meditation-starts), and of [eye movement during meditation](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/8522/254)

Answer (score 0):

In short this can be due to:

- past fabrications surfacing rapidly and creating uncommon experiences
- perhaps less likely but a possibility is [Piti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%ABti) which sometimes create vibrating and / or pulsating experiences

Also see: [eye movement during meditation](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/8693/295), [I get rapid eye movement as soon as meditation starts](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/14649/295)

These experiences are neither good nor bad. Also do not get attached or averse to them. In additions concentrate on the task at hand than giving importance and distracting your self when there experiences do arise in your meditation session.